# Wedge Sum of Two Spheres Homotopy Equivalent to a Compact Manifold?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

Let $X=S^2\vee S^2$ (wedge sum). The homology groups are $H_0(X,\mathbb{Z})= \mathbb{Z}$, $H_1(X,\mathbb{Z})= 0$, and $H_2(X,\mathbb{Z})= \mathbb{Z} \oplus\mathbb{Z}$.

I can see that $X$ is not homotopy equivalent to a closed manifold, since we would need a $\mathbb{Z}$ or $0$ in top homology (orientable, not orientable, resp) and torsion of $0$ or $\mathbb{Z_2}$ in the next lower homology (orientable, not orientable, resp), and we don't have that here.

So if $X$ is homotopy equivalent to some manifold, $M$, it must be one with boundary. The boundary would have to be composed of at least three components I believe... I'm thinking I could "fill out the two spheres to a 3 dimensional ball with the interiors of two disjoint open balls removed. This would be compact, 3-d manifold with boundary. However this looks like it isn't homotopy equivalent.

I also can see that by homotopy equivalence there are induced homomorphisms that are the identity on $H_*(X)$ and $H_*(M)$,but which pass through the other spaces homology. This gives that dim of $M$ must be atleast 3, but I'm guessing this allows me to say more...

Comment: Just take the regular neighborhood of the usual embedding of $S^2 \vee S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: You mean just "fill out" the two spheres a little bit? I see that that is homotopic to the wedge sum but is it homotopy equiv?

Comment: Remove two small $3$-balls from a large $3$-ball. This deformation retracts onto $S^2\vee S^2$.

Comment: Ah, nvm Lee. Thank u both

Comment: Also, there is a very general theorem that any reasonable tame subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a deformation retraction of a certain "regular neighborhood". The usual $S^2 \vee S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ falls under this theorem.

Comment: Someone should post that as an answer... :)

Comment: I think your observation about the number of components of the boundary is not true. If you take the regular neighborhood described in the other comment and take the product with the interval $[0,1]$ you should get a 4-manifold which deformation retracts to $S^2\vee S^2$ whose boundary counts just one component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any finite complex $X$ that is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in a piecewise smooth manner, $X$ has a *regular neighborhood* which is a compact $n$-manifold with boundary that deformation retracts to $X$.

In the case of the standard embedding $S^2 \vee S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, that regular neighborhood is as described by @DanielRust, and consists of large compact 3-ball from which two small open 3-balls have been removed, whose closures are disjoint subsets of the interior of the large ball.

Comment: Do you know of a reference for the existence of regular neighbourhoods?

Comment: The book by Rourke and Sanderson probably remains the best reference http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-81735-9